# SQL/PHP get all blogs, but only from my friends

Tags: php, sql, arrays, join

can you please help me with this little question?:

I have a website that features updates(like facebook), where everybody can write something. On one page, I want to display all blogs that were written by my friends, but I can't wrap my head around what SQL-Statement I need. I think of going through every blog and check whether UID(the author) is the same ID as the one from the table friends, where either usersend or userrecieved equals my UID. But I don't know if that trail of thought helps. Alternatively I can get an array of all blogs and an array of all friends

```
Table : Q1_IQLink_blogs

BID int(11)  
Theme   varchar(30)  
Text    longtext     
postDate    datetime     
UID int(11)  

Table : Q1_IQLink_friends

userSend    int(11)   
userRecieved    int(11)  
friendRequestStatus varchar(20)  
befreundetSeit  date
```

GOAL: Get all blogs that were written by my friends.

I thank in advance and hope for good luck.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Just select your all friends id and make it an array and then implode it so it will like 2,4,8 all your friend's id and then make the query  with where clause  like uid in(and put the list of ids here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, I know that you have a function called `db_getAllFriendsFromUser($UID);` that gives you every User, it returns an array with all the User info from your friends, select the UId in a `foreach` and make sth like `SELECT * FROM Q1_IQLink_blogs WHERE UID = ".$friendUID.";`

The function I mentioned(SQL Part)

```
SELECT *
  FROM Q1_IQLink_user as u
    JOIN Q1_IQLink_friends as f
      ON u.UID=f.UID
  WHERE (f.userSend='.$userId.' OR f.userRecieved='.$userId.') AND
        friendRequestStatus="angenommen";
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you need to have friend's id some how attached to 2nd table. IF you know your firend's id then the query is easy, just query in table 1 where UID = friend'sID